# Legendre's Constant

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-number-theorem

In a couple of web pages, I see that Legendre's constant is defined to be $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\pi(n) - (n/\log(n)))$ (for example, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Legendre%27s_constant.svg) and [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Legendre%27s_Constant)).

Actually the first uses $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\log(n) - (n/\pi(n)))$, but I have the same question in either case.

To be honest, I just assumed that this was a typo for $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\pi(n) / (n/\log(n)))$ (that is, the prime number theorem). However, in both pages it looks to me as if the claim really is that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\pi(n) - (n/\log(n)))$ exists and is $1$. Really?

I don't know whether to be more surprised that the limit exists or that its value is 1

Does anyone else find it surprising?

Comment: of course $f(n)=\pi(n) - (n/\log(n))$ does not have a limit, since $f(n+1)-f(n)$ does not have a limit

Comment: @JoséHdz.Stgo. Would you care to elaborate what did “Wikipedians get wrong”? I don’t see anything wrong at either https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Legendre%27s_constant.svg or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_constant . Wikipedia is not mentioned at the page you link to, nor does it seem to contradict  it.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: I stand corrected.

Comment: So just to summarize:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (log(n) - (n/\pi(n)))$$ exists and is equal to $1$,
whereas:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (\pi(n) - (n/log(n)))$$ does not exist.

I am still surprised at the former - it seems a better convergence than could be expected, but GH shows below how it comes about!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**1.** The prime number theorem in the form
$$\pi(n)=\mathrm{li}(n)+O(ne^{-c\sqrt{\log n}})$$
combined with the approximation
$$\mathrm{li}(n)=\frac{n}{\log n}+\frac{n}{\log^2 n}+O\left(\frac{n}{\log^3 n}\right)$$
shows that
$$\pi(n)-\frac{n}{\log n}=\frac{n}{\log^2 n}+O\left(\frac{n}{\log^3 n}\right).$$
So the left hand side tends to infinity quite rapidly, it has no finite limit.

**2.** The correct definition of Legendre's constant is
$$A:=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\log n-\frac{n}{\pi(n)}\right),$$
and the third display above shows that it equals $1$:
\begin{align*}\log n-\frac{n}{\pi(n)}
&=\log n-\frac{n}{\frac{n}{\log n}+\frac{n+o(n)}{\log^2 n}}\\
&=\log n-\frac{\log n}{1+\frac{1+o(1)}{\log n}}\\
&=(\log n)\left(1-\frac{1}{1+\frac{1+o(1)}{\log n}}\right)\\
&=(\log n)\left(1-1+\frac{1+o(1)}{\log n}\right)\\
&=(\log n)\frac{1+o(1)}{\log n}\\
&=1+o(1).\end{align*}

Answer (score 7):

I'll stay clear from the infamous $B_L'$ notation.

Legendre's original (correct) statement is that

$$\pi(x)=\frac{Bx}{\log x-A+o(1)}$$

where the so-called "Legendre's  constant" is $A$. The incorrect part was that he guessed that $A=1.08366$

As pointed out by Fedor Petrov, the definition with $\pi(n) - (n/\log(n))$ is clearly wrong.

---

**Note**. Using de la Vallée Poussin to disprove Legendre's conjecture is actually an overkill. This elementary argument is due to Pintz.

- János Pintz, "[On Legendre's prime number formula](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2321863)" (1980)

Let

$$\Psi(x)=Cx+\frac{(D+o(1))x}{\log x}$$

with some constants $C$ and $D$. Using Stirling and Legendre's formula,

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\log x+O(1) &= \frac{\log [x]!}{x}=\frac{1}{x} \sum_{n\leq x} \Lambda (n) \left[ \frac{x}{n} \right]\\ 
& = \sum_{n\leq x} \frac{\Lambda (n)}{n}+\frac{1}{x} \sum_{n\leq x} \Lambda (n)O(1)\\
& = \int_2^x \frac{\Psi(t)}{t^2}dt+\frac{\Psi(x)}{x}+O\left( \frac{\Psi(x)}{x}\right)\\
& = \int_2^x \frac{C+\frac{D+o(1)}{\log t}}{t}dt+O(1)\\
& = C\log x + (D+o(1))\log\log x.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Therefore $C=1$ and $D=0$, that is,

$$\Psi(x)=x\left(1+\frac{o(1)}{\log x}\right).$$

And by partial summation we finally get $A=B=1$ in Legendre's formula.

Comment: Wait... legendres conjecture is known to be false? D: I love trying to come up with tactics to prove it. Thanks for ruining the fun.

Comment: @Typhon The conjecture is true, it's just that $A=1$ exactly.

Comment: @Typhon no the same "Legrende's conjecture", I think... This is not the same one as in Landau's problems.

Comment: @Wojowu the conjecture is the formula? I thought we were referring to the whole "primes between any two squares" thing.

Comment: @Typhon We are talking about a completely different here.

Comment: @Wojowu alrighty.

Comment: What is supposed to be fixed in Wikipedia? I can’t see anything wrong on either https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Legendre%27s_constant.svg (which was linked in the question) or in the parent article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_constant . (The other link in the question is dead at the moment, but appears to go to “proofwiki”. Whatever that is, it is unrelated to Wikipedia, so I sincerely hope you are not bashing Wikipedia for someone else’s errors.)

Comment: @EmilJeřábek My mistake! I though I saw the wrong definition in the wikipedia article. I was wrong. I'll edit my answer.